# How can Jquery find all matching nodes, not just the first?

Tags: jquery

I try to get the contents of one or more nodes with jquery. When I do this:

```
xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        onload: function(data) {
            data = $.parseHTML(data.response);
            var vCard = $(data).find('.vcard')
            if (vCard.length === 1){
                var phone = vCard.find('.tel.row a').map(function(){
                    self.phone = this.text
                    console.log('')
                    console.log(url)
                    console.log(this)
                    callback();
                }).get()
            } else if(vCard.length > 1){
                self.getPhone()
            }
        }
    })
```

I just get the value first node. I would like to get all of the nodes.

Comment: The callback you pass to `map()` is quite strange and won't project anything. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm doing an xml_httpRequest, updating the question

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var phone = vCard.find('.tel.row a').map(function(){
   return this.text
 }).get()
```

now the variable `phone` is an array containing the texts of all `.tel.row a` elements

Comment: The .get is there, sorry!

Comment: @KristofferNolgren i added a `return` statement